# How do I change the linear stiffness of an object programmatically?

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, physics, soft-body

I want to programmatically change the linear stiffness of some soft body objects I'm working with. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to batch-modify physics values on objects, you could do something like this:

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.game.physics_type == 'SOFT_BODY':
        obj.game.soft_body.linear_stiffness += 0.1 #or whatever other operation
```

I'm not really familiar with the BGE, though.